# What is the best way to copy memory for X indexes to many locations within a single array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

What is the best way to copy memory for X indexes to many locations within a single array in C?

The problem trying to be solved is emulated memory for a CPU emulator. The original hardware has this type of memory mirroring, and I am attempting to replicate it via code.

Say you have an array:

```
int memory[100] = {0};
```

and you have 10 indexes which are mirrored at different locations. For example if `memory[0]` is changed, index 0, 10, 20, 30... should change to that value or if `memory[3]` is changed, index 3, 13, 23, 33 should be mirrored.

Likewise if any mirrored location is changed all other mirror locations should reflect this, such as if index 23 is changed, 3, 13, 23, 33... etc should reflect this.

Another requirement is a way to specify where the start and ends of the mirrored locations are. For example index 10-19 could be mirrored at index 30-39, then again at 70-79 leaving unmodified space in between segments of mirrored indexes.

Would using memcpy be the fastest/most efficient way of achieving this if this, or would some sort of iterating loop and pointer math be better for efficiency? How would the pointer math be done to calculate the start address to copy to as well as the destination? Would an array of pointers holding the start addresses that live inside the memory array be the best way to handle this?

Something maybe like (this probably won't compile it is just pseudo code for an idea of mine):

```
#define NUMBER_OF_MIRRORS 3
#define LENGTH_OF_MIRRORS 10
int  memory[100]             = {0};
int *memory_mirror_starts[3] = {&memory[10], &memory[30], &memory[70]};

// When memory needs to be mirrored
for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_MIRRORS; i++) {
   for(int n = 0; n < LENGTH_OF_MIRRORS; n++) {
       memory_mirror_starts[i][n] = memory_mirror_starts[0][n];
   }
}
```

I think I may be on the right track, but this wouldn't satisfy all my requests since this specifically copies the results of the first mirror to the rest. If a write was to any of the other mirrors it would be overwritten rather than copied to the other mirrors.

Thanks for any tips and advice.

Comment: This question was asked yesterday I think.

Comment: @iharob Could you find a link for it?

Comment: Why not writing a function to poke an int at a specific location `set(int index, int val)` that actually writes to all mirrors, instead of a direct access to arrays?

Comment: @ring0 What would be the neatest way to also pass the different starting locations of the mirrors? Just an array of pointers to the start of each mirror along with the index/value? What is the correct way to define an array of pointers which point into a single array like I have described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify where each mirror starts in the `memory` array, the "array of pointers into 'memory' works",

```
int *memory_mirror_starts[3] = {&memory[10], &memory[30], &memory[70]}; // (A)
```

or you could simply give each offset:

```
int memory_mirror_starts[3] = { 10, 30, 70 }; // (B)
```

Then to ensure each write to a given mirror is indeed replicated to all mirrors, without copying the whole thing all the time, you could have a `poke` function to write at a given index in a mirror (for each approach, (A) and (B))

```
void poke(int index, int value) {
   int j;
   for (j=0 ; j<NUMBER_OF_MIRRORS ; j++) 
      memory_mirror_starts[j][index] = value; // (A)
}
```

or

```
void poke(int index, int value) {
   int j;
   for (j=0 ; j<NUMBER_OF_MIRRORS ; j++) 
      memory[memory_mirror_starts[j] + index] = value; // (B)
}
```

Having a function to centralize write access hides the mirrors complexity to developers and ensures all mirrors are indeed updated correctly.

Note `index` could be checked to be `>=0` and `< LENGTH_OF_MIRRORS`.

Performance wise,

- adding `inline` to the functions declarations will change the function calls with the function code in place, saving the calls. The `poke` function being small, the code shouldn't get much bigger.
- (A) does basically `*(*(memory_mirror_starts + j) + index) = value`
- (B) does basically `*(memory + *(memory_mirror_starts + j) + index) = value`
- so (A) could be a tad faster, (but optimizers have their say, and it is better to test both solutions)

Inline:

```
inline void poke(int index, int value) { ...
```

Comment: Perfect thank you! Just as a question of curiosity if you happen to know; performance wise if this were to be called X times per second, would version A or version B be more efficient at completing its task the fastest. Or would the difference be so marginal that it wouldn't matter.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about the inline declaration.